# What are the differences between the $n$ permutations of the Edwards & Penney Differential Equations books?

Tags: textbooks, differential-equations

Edwards and Penney are the authors of a [popular differential equations textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321796985).  Bizarrely, there seem to be $2^4$ permutations of the title:

1. Some versions have "Elementary" and some don't
2. Some versions have "with [or 'and'] Boundary Value Problems" and some don't
3. Some versions have "and Linear Algebra", some don't
4. Some versions have "Computing and Modeling", some don't

That's aside from the numerous editions of each.

What are the differences between them?  Is there a core book, with the permutations simply adding chapters - or is there a difference in content and writing?

Comment: I love this question. I don't have an answer, but this is one of my main pet peeves with using a textbook. The inevitable multiplicity of editions creates all sorts of problems since students invariably and inexoriably will get a different edition, and/or the bookstore will requre me to require an edition which is way more expensive than what is easily available. Fwiw, I've got the BVP version somewhere in my basement, but I think I only have one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question related to Maths Education.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I'm not sure about Edwards and Penney, but I've heard that there was a long and heated discussion on our textbook committee whether to use "Calculus" or "Calculus with early transcendentals" by Stewart (when googling the exact title, I learned that now there exists also "Calculus: Early Transcendentals"). The only difference between these two was that chapters 3 and 4 were swapped together with related exercises, etc. Well, everybody needs a few pennies to buy bread and water, even the calculus textbook writers :lol:

Comment: @MahdiMajidi-Zolbanin, if this is question about textbook selection for a course, then perhaps it is appropriate for Math Educators.

Comment: Brannan, Boyce and DiPrima, or at least dedicates half a page to the differences from the other editions.  From "DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS:An Introduction to Modern Methods and Applications" by James R. Brannan | William E. Boyce. 3rd edition, preface page vii.   "Relation of This Text to Boyce and DiPrima
Brannan and Boyce is an offshoot of the well-known textbook by Boyce and DiPrima. Readers familiar with Boyce and DiPrima will doubtless recognize in the present book some of
the hallmark features that distinguish that textbook.
....

Comment: To help avoid confusion among potential users of either text, the primary differences are
described below:
▶ Brannan and Boyce is more sharply focused on the needs of students of engineering
and science, whereas Boyce and DiPrima targets a somewhat more general audience,
including engineers and scientists.
▶ Brannan and Boyce is intended to be more consistent with the way contemporary scientists and engineers actually use differential equations in the workplace.
▶ Brannan and Boyce emphasizes systems of first order equation, introducing them earlier, and also examining them inmore detail

Comment: than Boyce and DiPrima. Brannan and
Boyce has an extensive appendix on matrix algebra to support the treatment of systems
in n dimensions.
▶ Brannan and Boyce integrates the use of computers more thoroughly than Boyce and
DiPrima, and assumes that most students will use computers to generate approximate
solutions and graphs throughout the book.
▶ Brannan and Boyce emphasizes contemporary applications to a greater extent than
Boyce and DiPrima, primarily through end-of-chapter projects.

Comment: ▶ Brannan and Boyce makes somewhat more use of graphs, with more emphasis on phase
plane displays, and uses engineering language (e.g., state variables, transfer functions,
gain functions, and poles) to a greater extent than Boyce and DiPrima.

Comment: How does the publisher for Edwards and describe the differences?  Hopefully, it's more specific than simply marketing speak.

Comment: @nickalh, that's a lot to put in comments. Might it be better posted in the form of a (partial) answer? Or trim the comments? Just wondering.

Comment: @nickalh For Edwards & Penney, I can't find any explanation from the publisher

Comment: @JW I own an Edwards and Penney Diff. Eq. book, but it's 30 years old, probably long before the variety of editions existed.
My comments might be off topic.  Possibly useful to other readers but don't really answer the question asked.  If there's enough agreement to post as an answer I will.